# Without using VM or MAC how can i do IOS development

Tags: c#, ios, mobile-development

I want to start IOS development as i prefer ios over android and other platforms due to personal liking only.

The problem is i tried Visual Studio with Xamarin but it needs an actual MAC for apps !!

I am thinking about using Xamarin Studio! 
Does it require a MAC too ?
Any other way around without using VM or MAC ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use C# with the Xamarin Framework or use Ionic 2/3 (Angular 2/4), React Native.
For Xamarin, you could actually build your app but you'll need a Mac to be connected remotely to your Windows machine in order to build the iOS project.